# How to get the right launch image in iOS9 programmatically?

Tags: ios, launchimage

I've add different size images into LaunchImage asset. While I use this code

```
UIImage *launchImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage"]
```

It has returned the launchImage with the wrong size, exactly returns @2x png. When i use iphone6 plus, the expecting image is @3x png. 
Any idea about getting the right image?

Comment: WHY CANT YOU SET DIRECTLY

Comment: Actually, I want to use the launch image not for launching app.

Comment: ok. Because it already exist in imagecassets name LaunchImage so you are replacing that one. it is not possible to do like that.

Comment: then you need to use same image with different  name.

Comment: It will duplicate many images for different screen size.

Answer (score 5):

After searching a lot, i found that the LaunchImages are special, and aren't actually an asset catalog on the device. And the launchImage file name for all iOS devices list as:

- LaunchImage-568h@2x.png
- LaunchImage-700-568h@2x.png
- LaunchImage-700-Landscape@2x~ipad.png
- LaunchImage-700-Landscape~ipad.png
- LaunchImage-700-Portrait@2x~ipad.png
- LaunchImage-700-Portrait~ipad.png
- LaunchImage-700@2x.png
- LaunchImage-Landscape@2x~ipad.png
- LaunchImage-Landscape~ipad.png
- LaunchImage-Portrait@2x~ipad.png
- LaunchImage-Portrait~ipad.png
- LaunchImage.png
- LaunchImage@2x.png
- LaunchImage-800-667h@2x.png (iPhone 6)
- LaunchImage-800-Portrait-736h@3x.png (iPhone 6 Plus Portrait)
- LaunchImage-800-Landscape-736h@3x.png (iPhone 6 Plus
  Landscape)

so if you want to get the right launch image for iphone device, just use this code:

```
    NSString *launchImageName;
    if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height > 667.0f) {
        launchImageName = @"LaunchImage-800-736h"; // iphone6 plus
    }
    else if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height > 568.0f) {
        launchImageName = @"LaunchImage-800-667h"; // iphone6
    }
    else if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height > 480.0f){
        launchImageName = @"LaunchImage-700-568h";// iphone5/5plus
    } else {
        launchImageName = @"LaunchImage-700"; // iphone4 or below
    }
    UIImage *launchImage = [UIImage imageNamed:launchImageName];
```

Comment: It works, however, for the iPhone 6 Plus, you need to include the orientation as well. So it should be "LaunchImage-800-Portrait-736h" for portrait mode. Thanks!

Comment: What are the "special" names for iphone-x and newer? anybody knows?